GoogleCredentials.refreshIfExpired returning a new access token everytime
I am trying to get an access token for FCM v1 using the below code.
static String SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging";
private static String getAccessToken() throws IOException {
  GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
          .getApplicationDefault()
          .createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPES));
  // googleCredentials.refresh();
  googleCredentials.refreshIfExpired();   // Doesn't work either
  return googleCredentials.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
}

I am able to get the token and publish messages to FCM. The problem is that everytime I call refreshIfExpired(), it gives me a new token even if the previous one is not expired. Is this expected? Shall I check for expiry at my end? I am guessing there would be some rate limiter to fetch new tokens. I also tried to have a common GoogleCredentials object but still the same issue.
Where is the refresh token stored? Where does it check for access token expiry (client or server)?
I tried to read the documentation but it's not clear enough for me. I need some clear understanding on this and a way to refresh the token only when it's expired.

Not a Java dev. Your function recreates GoogleCredentials upon every invocation. If you getApplicationDefault() and retain the credentials and then check the credentials for refreshIfExpired, the credentials should not be recreated each time.

If you are using service account to create the access token , then it doesn't create refresh token .
Service Accounts don't have refresh tokens.You have to redo the authentication process when sending message.
Even i am getting this in token response.
  refresh_token: 'jwt-placeholder'


It's because you create a new instance of GoogleCredentials.class each time. Create one instance of GoogleCredentials.class and use the same one to call the refreshIfExpired() method. It works as expected.
2 code snippets here:
01. Configuration class:
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.yml"})
public class GoogleCredentialsConfig {

    @Value("${fcm_private_key_file_path}")
    String googleServiceAccountPrivateKeyFilePath;

    @Bean
    public GoogleCredentials getGoogleCredentials() {
        try {
            FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(googleServiceAccountPrivateKeyFilePath);
            GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
                    .fromStream(serviceAccount)
                    .createScoped(List.of(
                            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"
                    ));
            return googleCredentials;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("ERROR OCCURRED WHILE GENERATING FCM ACCESS TOKEN: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

02. Creating a new token if expired:
public String getServiceAccountAccessToken() throws IOException {
    GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = googleCredentialsConfig.getGoogleCredentials();
    googleCredentials.refreshIfExpired();
    String accessToken = googleCredentials.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    return accessToken;
}

